# Formatar JSON - PHP e MySql?

Tags: php, mysql, json

Estou precisando montar um `json` da seguinte forma:

```
[
 {"SUPERMECADO 1": {"telefones": [ "1999999999","1999999991"]}  },
 {"SUPERMECADO 2": {"telefones": [ "1999999992","1999999993"]}  }
]
```

Mas, atualmente minha `SQL` esta retornando um `array` assim:

```
[
 {"campanha":"SUPERMECADO1","telefone":"1999999999"},
 {"campanha":"SUPERMECADO1", telefone":"1999999991"},
 {"campanha":"SUPERMECADO2", telefone":"1999999992"},
 {"campanha":"SUPERMECADO2", telefone":"1999999993"}
]
```

o meu código `PHP`:

```
$query = "SELECT campanha, telefone FROM rest";
$query = mysql_query($query);
$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
echo json_encode($rows);
```

Como posso montar meu código `PHP` para que eu mostre todos os telefones agrupando os nomes da campanha?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente assim no seu código:

```
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) 
{
    $rows[$r['campanha']]['telefones'][] = $r['telefone'];
}
```

[*Exemplo Online IDEONE*](http://ideone.com/IQxeDS)

Comment: obrigado @virgilio funcionou, vou colocar sua resposta como correta